# Last characters trimmed in codeigniter captcha when image default width decreased

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha

I am using codeIgniter 3.1.11.
Default width of captcha image is `150` that contains all the words inside the captcha image.
But when I changed the `img_width` to `50` according to my need, it is trimming last characters.
Code is as follows:

```
$vals = array(
        'word'          => '',
        'img_path'      => './assets/captcha/',
        'img_url'       => base_url().'assets/captcha/',
        'font_path'     => base_url().'assets/fonts/FontAwesome.ttf',
        'img_width'     => 50, // Default is 150 & less than 150 crops last characters
        'img_height'    => 30,
        'expiration'    => 7200,
        'word_length'   => 4,
        'font_size'     => 100,
        'img_id'        => 'cap_img',
        'pool'          => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',

        // White background and border, black text and red grid
        'colors'        => array(
                'background' => array(255, 255, 255),
                'border' => array(255, 255, 255),
                'text' => array(0, 0, 0),
                'grid' => array(255, 40, 40)
        )
);

$cap = create_captcha($vals);

$data = array(
  'captcha_time'  => $cap['time'],
  'ip_address'    => $this->input->ip_address(),
  'word'          => $cap['word']
);

echo $cap['image'];
```

This is output image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple...

You have to do one thing
Go to Captcha_helper.php and search

instead of

```
        $x = mt_rand(0, $img_width / ($length / 3));
```

Do Like this

```
        $x = mt_rand(0, $img_width / ($length / 1));
```